# Windows 7 Task Scheduler will not open web page

Tags: url, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have read a dozen articles on here, and tried over 50 different syntax variations in task scheduler, and bat files with several different syntax variations, and it still will not work.  All of the articles' answers fail, along with everything else I have tried.

Here's the task: Monday through Friday at 4:55 AM, launch a browser and navigate without user interaction to westcoastswing.radio.net.  It doesn't matter which browser.  Task must run Monday through Friday only.  Task must run whether anyone is logged in or not, and must wake the computer to run the task.  Monday through Friday at 6:15 AM, kill the browser.

Updating to a newer version of Windows is not an option at this time.  A third party product is only an option once it's determined that Microsoft is deliberately blocking this functionality.  Using Windows Media Player and a specialized URL found via F12 might be an option, but I have spent an even greater amount of time trying to get that strategy to work, without success.

Thanks for any help or advice.  Please don't mark this as a duplicate, I have tried the existing similar articles and their solutions do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a method that works, but only because I use MSIE only for this and nothing else.

1. Specify full path to IE, in quotes, in start program.
2. Specify URL, not in quotes, in optional arguments.
3. Highest possible permission.
4. Don't run "hidden".

I don't know why that worked, or why out of all the combinations I tried before I didn't hit on that exact one, but sorry for posting a pointless question.